# How can I create a queue group via the API

Tags: apex, trigger, rest-api, soap-api, java

So in testing, I've figured out that a queue is a type of Group. I'm trying to POST a new group, then change its Type from "regular" to "queue", but in doing so, I get this error message:

> Unable to create/update fields: Type. Please check the security
>   settings of this field and verify that it is read/write for your
>   profile or permission set.

Is there anyway I can either change the Group type from "regular" to "queue" **OR** just create it as a new Queue by default, through the API?

If its not available through the API, would there be a way to create an Apex trigger that would change the group type to "queue" (instead of "regular") after creation?

Answer (score 2):

The type field is *createable*, but not *updateable*. You must make the group as a queue in order to have it work as a queue. Afterwards, you can insert the GroupMember and QueueSObject records to specify the users and roles, and available sobjects for the queue.

---

You'll want to take a look at the "[Sobject Tree](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_sobject_tree.htm)" resource to help you create this data. Here's an example:

```
POST /services/data/v43.0/composite/tree/Group HTTP/1.1
Host: mydomain.my.salesforce.com
Authorization: Bearer mysessionid
Content-Length: 372
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Accept: application/json

{
    "records": [
        {
            "attributes": { "type": "Group", "referenceId": "queueReference" },
            "DeveloperName": "SuperQueue",
            "Name": "SuperQueue",
            "Type": "Queue",
            "QueueSobjects": {
                "records": [
                    {
                        "attributes": { "type": "QueueSobject", "referenceId": "queueCaseSObject" },
                        "SObjectType": "Case"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```